# How to increase the duration of :active in css?

Tags: html, css

So want the green background color to stay longer than the button being pressed. Is it possible?

```css
#button {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
#button:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" id="button">1</a> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use :focus ? http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vczme9p7/

Comment: i dont want it to be that long....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible use `transition`

```css
#button {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  transition:0s 1s;
}
#button:active {
  background-color: green;
  transition:0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" id="button">1</a> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's great; however I'd suggest you to decrease duration so as not to make the people be nervous waiting for the green color to go away :D

Comment: @MeghGandhi Edit `transition:0s 1s;` to `transition:0s .5s;`

Comment: -webkit-transition:0s 0.5s;
    like this?

Comment: u have to long click it for 0.5s...thats the problem

Comment: so any way to increase the duration without the long click?

Comment: @MeghGandhi What are you talking about can you give me a fiddle link ?

Comment: @Akshay can tell what does `transition:0s 0.5s;` mean? why two digits?