# Can't Increase :active duration in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to increase the duration of CSS :active and found this thread [How to increase the duration of :active in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939950/how-to-increase-the-duration-of-active-in-css) I tried this but it didn't work on my code.
here my code:

```css
li {
  transition:0s 1s;
}

li:active:before {
  content:"hello !";
  z-index:99999999;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  background:black;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 0;
  transition:0s;
}
```

```html
<li>Style This</li>
```

Comment: there is no transition ... you are adding a pseudo element and not doing any transition to li

Comment: In li have no :active pseudo class.

Comment: @Hanif there is, you can test the snippet and see

Comment: So, How do I increase duration for :before content

Comment: Duration of what? It has to go from one style(s) to a different style(s). example `font-size:0` to `font-size:30px` or `opacity: 0` to `opacity:1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `:active` rule will stop matching as soon as the mouse button is released. thus the `:before` will be removed.

You could render the block, and not display it until the `:active` starts matching.

caveat: If the `:before` block is clicked, its parent will also become active.
In the end, I would opt for a JavaScript solution.

```css
li {
  transition:0s 1s;
}
li:before{
 content:"hello !";
  z-index:99999999;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  background:black;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 0;
  transition:1s;
  opacity:0;
}

li:active:before {
 display:block;
 opacity:1;
  transition:0s;
}
```

```html
<li>Style This</li>
```

Comment: @AjayMalik are you sure this solve your issue ? there is only a transition applied and there is no increase in the duration

Comment: But I understand Now How to increase it, Thanks for giving me an idea about animation

Answer (score 0):

The trick won't work as you expect simply because there is no transition applied to the `li` element.

You need first to understand how it works. Here is a simple example:

```css
.box {
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  transition:0s 1s;
}
.box:active {
  background:green;
  transition:0s;
]
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

When you click, the active state is considered; thus the transition is set to `0s` and the background become immediately green. When you release the mouse, the active state is no more considered and we have the new transition with a dely so the the background go back to red after this delay.

So in order to have such think, you may consider doing the same but with the pseudo element:

```css
li:before {
  content: "hello !";
  z-index: 99999999;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 0s 4s;
}

li:active::before{
  opacity:1;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<li>Style This</li>
```

I considred opacity but it can work with any [animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).